# nginx proxy_pass domain with subfolder to localhost with port test.com/test to localhost:9001

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass

i am trying to get nginx to pass

```
"your-domain.com/test"
```

to

```
http://localhost:{9001}
```

i am new to nginx and had success with the following:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name your-domain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:{9001};
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

Now i am able to pass my domain to the port 9001.
Now i want to adapt this in that way, that i am able to pass your-domain.com/test to localhost:{9001}.
Is this possible? what do i have to change?

i tried

```
location /test
server_name your-domain.com/test
```

both without success.

Comment: you want both `/` and `/test` to pass to `9001` ?

Comment: i want your-domain.com/test to prox_pass to 9001. is this possible?

Comment: I believe you don't need to change any thing because `location /` will also match `location /test` so it will get `proxy_pass`ed also

Answer (score 1):

```
location ~ /test
```

In fact, location need an operator (=, ~ ...) to match an uri.
"location /" mean 'everything'.